# Converting GBFS to GIS files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

Has anyone worked with GBFS(General Bikeshare Feed Specification) files? I'd like to convert  locations of the bike share stations to a GIS file compatible with ArcGIS. This is an example of a feed that has latitude and longitude in: https://gbfs.bcycle.com/bcycle_madison/station_information.json.  I have tried the JSON to Features tool in ArcGIS and also opening it in Excel as a text file.  The format of the feed does not seem to be compatible. I am using ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.7.1 and ArcGIS Pro Advanced 2.9.7.

Comment: QGIS has a plugin for this https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GBFS-NOW/ I checked it out and it works for the url https://gbfs.bcycle.com/bcycle_madison/gbfs.json

Comment: if you add a QGIS tag - will post the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks. I will take a look on my home computer. Unfortunately QGIS is not available on our office workstations.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to parse the Json file in Excel so that I could use Display XY Data in ArcGIS.